# Objective-C setImage forState:UIControlStateNormal not formatting image properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, uibutton

I'm new to objective-c so please bear with me. I'm working on some code as an exercise, from the Stanford course "Programming for the iPhone/iPad" in the winter of 2013. Basically what I need to do is set an image as a button for the button's UIControlStateNormal. Unfortunately, I can't post pictures yet to stack overflow, but when I try to set the image on the button for the UIControlState normal, the images for the buttons are all over the place and are larger than the actual buttons. For the other UIControlState options, the buttons with the image behave as expected. There are sixteen buttons in total.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have the button images being set in a for loop in the application's ViewController within the method called "updateUI". Here is the code:

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property (nonatomic) int flipCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic)CardMatchingGame* game;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastFlipLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *lastFlip;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *gameControl;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController
//lazy instantiation of the game
-(CardMatchingGame *)game
{
    if(!_game)
    {
        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:self.cardButtons.count usingDeck:[[PlayingCardDeck alloc]init]];
    }
    return _game;
}
//set the properties of the card buttons
-(void)setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons
{
    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
    [self updateUI];
}
//method to update the UI
-(void)updateUI
{
    UIImage* cardback = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback.png"];//loads in the pic for the cardback
    //go through all the card buttons and update
    for(UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons)
    {
        Card* card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];//get the card
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isUnplayable;
        cardButton.alpha = card.isUnplayable ? 0.2 : 1.0;
        if(cardback)
        {
             [cardButton setImage:cardback forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [cardButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",self.game.score];
    }
    self.lastFlip = self.game.lastFlip;//get the result of the last flip from the model
    [self.gameControl setTitle:@"2-Card \n Game" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.gameControl setTitle:@"3-Card \n Game" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
    self.flipCount++;
    [self updateUI];
}
//setter for flipCount, update to the UI
-(void)setFlipCount:(int)flipCount
{
    _flipCount = flipCount;
    self.flipsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d",self.flipCount];
}
//setter for lastFlips, update to the UI
-(void)setLastFlip:(NSArray *)lastFlip
{
    _lastFlip = lastFlip;
    //append the last flips together to display the status
    NSString* cardString = [[NSString alloc]init];
    cardString = [self.lastFlip componentsJoinedByString:@" and "];
    if(self.lastFlip.count==1 && ![cardString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.lastFlipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You just flipped the %@", cardString];
    }
    else if(self.lastFlip.count!=1 && self.game.lastMatch)
    {
        self.lastFlipLabel.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"You just matched the %@ \n for %d points!",cardString, self.game.lastScore];
    }
    else if(self.lastFlip.count!=1 && !self.game.lastMatch)
    {
        self.lastFlipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Oohh, sorry the %@ don't match. %d points for you!", cardString,  self.game.lastScore];
    }
}
//reset the game
- (IBAction)resetGame:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc]initWithCardCount:self.cardButtons.count usingDeck:[[PlayingCardDeck alloc]init]];
    [self.game reset];
    self.lastFlipLabel.text = @"";//reset the text so it's blank
    self.flipCount = 0;
    [self updateUI];
}


@end
```

Comment: Also, I'm running this on an iOS 6.1 simulator.

Comment: Maybe it is conflicting with your `@""` title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off auto layout - in the right hand panel of your storyboard view in Xcode.

Comment: Woo! That worked, but now I have another problem. The image I set for UIControlStateNormal is also showing up after the button is clicked. What should show up is a string representing the card (ie "A♣" etc). If I set the image for UIControlStateNormal, why is it also appearing in UIControlStateSelected?

Comment: great - mark as correct please. Does the image appear when you press it at all ? Then changes back to controlstatenormal ?

Comment: Yes the image appears, but it appears for both ControlStateNormal and after the button is selected, which I understand from the API to be UIControlStateSelected. What should happen is that after you click on the button the "card" should "flip over" to reveal the string that represents that card. The cards still have the correct strings assigned to them but the image that I set with this line: [cardButton setImage:cardback forState:UIControlStateNormal]; is also appearing after the button has been pressed.

Comment: If the correct image is displayed while you are holding down the button then u need this as well - sender.selected = !sender.isSelected; As once you let go of touch the button its not selected. This line will make it act more like a on / off button